# JIT debugger not working when using source generation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, jit, sourcegenerators

This is my first attempt at creating a question so bear with me.

I'm attempting to implement a source generator into my solution. I was able to get the project to compile and work at a debugging state (while going through some erros) but the source generator in the end never generated the files. Please see below:

I would get these errors when attaching the debugger:

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XSNz.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT2Hl.png)

[Error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsu6B.png)

If I didn't attach to the debugger then the popup doesn't show up, however it doesn't generate the files.

And when debugging and letting the process finish:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcP3c.png)

Here is my code for the project to see if maybe I did something wrong setting it up.

[Project reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnQxI.png)

[Gen Project file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOON1.png)

I've tried:

- Repairing visual studio
- Repairing (reinstalling) .net sdk (.net 472, 48, Core 3.1, and 5.0)
- Reinstalling the dotnet folder in program files
- Running the same project in Jetbrains Rider (The error on there said "An unhandled exception occured in [21596] dotnet.exe" with a similar "Available debuggers" popup window)

Comment: Those errors look pretty nasty, but you'll probably need to describe in some detail how you got to that point.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Lol I really just created a simple generator yesterday and could never get it to work, there's not much to it. What kind of details would you be interested in?

Comment: attaching the debugger to a source generator? you usually don't debug your source generator at it's actual runtime at all, but by tests in wich you use the CSharpGeneratorDriver class or one of the other methods to set it up manually to run and debug your generator. using MSBuildWorkspace you can even get it to process an actual project like it would at runtime

Comment: @PatrickBeynio, you can just add `Debugger.Launch` to your source generator and happily debug your source generators in the real world.   (just remove that line when you've diagnosed the problem.)  On debug builds I typically wrap everything in a try/catch and then call `Debugger.Launch` in the `catch` handler so I can fix the bug.

Comment: @KirkWoll oh that's true. the rules in my head deny me to use it myself, but should definitely keep that in mind as an easy alternative if someone seeks help in the future, thanks.